# JQuery (update form) - How-to pre-populate multiple selects first, then populate record data

Tags: jquery, forms, asynchronous

I'm new to JQuery and I've been going mad over the last couple of days trying to resolve this.

I'm working on a form used to update a customer order. What I'm trying to do is to first load the related select data (Order status, Supervisor, Seller's Group, Seller's list) and then (and only then) to load the order information (and select the correct option from the drop-down boxes).

There are a lot of selects, so they have to be loaded asynchronously or else the page takes ages to load (and freezes in the meantime). The problem is, the form data ends up loading before the drop-downs, and the correct options are never selected.

I tried to solve it using JQuery deferrends, but the form population always ends up firing before the selects are populated.

Here is a reduced version of my code (with just one select):

```
populateStates = function(field){
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();     
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-json-states.php",
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
                    var options = ''; 
                    $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                        options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                    });     
                    $("select#"+field).html(options);
                    // Sort options alphabetically
                    sortListAlpha(field);
                    // Append option: "all"
                    appendListItem(field, '0', 'All');
                    // Select first item
                    selectFistItem(field);  
                    // Resolve Deferred
                    dfd.resolve();              
        }
    }); 
    return dfd.promise(); // Returns a promise              
}
populateFormGeneric = function (j, target) {
    $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
        switch ($('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('type')) {
            case 'select-one': 
                if (value==null) {
                    $('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('value', '')
                } else {
                    $('#'+target+'-'+key).attr('value', value)                              
                }
                break;
        }                                           
    });         
}   
populateCustomer = function(id){
    $.ajax({
        url: "get-json-customer.php?id="+id,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (j) {
            $.when(populateStates('state_id')).then(populateFormGeneric(j, "form1"));   
        }
    });         
}
```

As you can see, the "populateFormGeneric" fires no matter what happens with the "populateStates" function (I can even leave it empty and it fires anyway).

Please help. Much appreciated,
Edward

Comment: Have you tried calling populateCustomer in populateState succes?

Comment: you really should register your account so that you can edit your question without having to go through the approval process.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be because you `return dfd.promise()` before the `success()` function runs in `populateStates()`.

What happens if you just call `populateFormGeneric()` from within the `success()` function of the AJAX request of `populateStates()`?

```
var populateStates = function(field){
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (j) {
                var options = ''; 
                $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
                    options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
                });     
                $("select#"+field).html(options);
                // Sort options alphabetically
                sortListAlpha(field);
                // Append option: "all"
                appendListItem(field, '0', 'All');
                // Select first item
                selectFistItem(field);

                populateFormGeneric(j, 'form1');
        }
    });
},
populateFormGeneric = function (j, target) {
    $.each(j, function(key, value) { 
        ...
    });         
},   
populateCustomer = function(id){
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function (j) {
            populateStates('state_id');
        }
    });         
};
```